# How to activate a SQL trigger only when a value doesn't exist in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I was wondering how you would write a trigger which will only be activated when the value you want to insert doesn't exist, and I need to create a reference for it in another table before it gets added. I keep on getting an error for this current code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CreateConversation
    BEFORE INSERT ON Messages
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (select convID FROM Conversation where new.convID = convID ))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Conversation (convID, msgID) VALUES(:new.convID, :new.msgID);
    END;
/
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your data model seems a little strange.  But, if the row you are inserting into `CONVERSATION` is unique, then one simple way is to just try the insert every time.  If the value already exists, it'll raise a `dup_val_on_index` exception, which you can ignore.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CreateConversation
    BEFORE INSERT ON Messages
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Conversation (convID, msgID) VALUES(:new.convID, :new.msgID);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
        NULL;
    END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately I'm getting a ORA-04098 error

Comment: The error seems to be coming from the "INSERT INTO Conversation line..... " But I have no idea what I typed incorrectly. In another trigger I have an UPDATE statement for a table and it works fine. And I don't have any triggers for when the table Conversation is changed.

Comment: Start with the obvious: look in DBA_TRIGGERS for any triggers either of the two tables `MESSAGES` or `CONVERSATION` that are not valid.  It is not necessarily either of the two trigger you've mentioned already.